# kql query to compare the hour which has minimum number of TriggersStarted from last week to today past hour TriggersStarted

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitoring

I tried below  query to compare the hour which has min number of TriggersStarted ) from past 1 week to TriggersStarted from last 1 hour today.But i am failing to join the both tables as i dont have common column to merge the both tables.

[image]

```
AzureMetrics
| where TimeGenerated between ( ago(7d) .. endofday(ago(1d)) )
| where MetricName == "TriggersStarted"
| summarize LastWeek=count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)
//| sort by TimeGenerated desc
| summarize min_triigers = min(LastWeek)
| join
(
AzureMetrics
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where MetricName == "TriggersStarted"
| summarize TodaysoFar=count()
) on ( cant find common coulmn)
```

i couldnt be able to add two tables beacuse i dont have common column between them. could u tell me Is there any possibility to use other approach to get it done or should i use another functions?

Comment: Please avoid tag spamming. You are not using kqlmagic and askql isn't even related to kql.

Comment: This query doesn't make much sense, business wise. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: **comparing the hour which has min number of TriggersStarted from past 1 week to TriggersStarted from last 1 hour today based on that i will create a alert in log analytics workspace**. This is what i am really trying to do. And when it comes to query ( first part)i am able to get the TriggersStarted per hour from last 7 days to till yesterday and ( second part)TriggersStarted from last one hour. and finally comparing them  **last one hour triggers > hour which has min triggers from last week**

Comment: **(1)** The way you wrote it, the 1st time slot count, is dependent on your query execution time. If you run your query on 8:30, 9:30 etc., this timeslot will contain events of only 30 minutes. If you run your query on 8:45, 9:45 etc., this timeslot will contain events of only 15 minutes. In other words, the 1st slot is likely to be found as the one with the minimum number of events, simply because you are not looking on a whole hour.

Comment: **(2)** Let say that there is an operational problem, you got 1 event during the last hour and your alert goes on. Great, but from that point for at least 1 week, your alert is not going to be triggered again, because the latest hour result will always be greater from the weekly minimum.

Comment: **(3)** You have built-in capabilities of anomaly detection. It just doesn't make sense to write such a query. Even if you decide to do so for some reason, looking on the weekly hourly minimum is probably one of the worst statistical ways to do so.

Comment: Thanks @DavidדודוMarkovitz  for the explaination and feedback.

Comment: Sorry, **(4)** was wrong :-) Deleted. You are not going to identify hours during the week that had no events, but you are going to identify if the last hour has no events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure a `join` is required. You can try getting both scalar values using `toscalar()` then `print`ing them in a single row.

For example:

```
let last_week = toscalar(
  AzureMetrics
  | where TimeGenerated between ( ago(7d) .. endofday(ago(1d)) )
  | where MetricName == "TriggersStarted"
  | summarize LastWeek=count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)
  | summarize min(LastWeek)
);
let last_hour = toscalar(
  AzureMetrics
  | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
  | where MetricName == "TriggersStarted"
  | summarize count()
);
print last_week, last_hour
```