# Need a KQL query to compare count of failed APIs for today in a specific time with respect to Count of APIs that failed yesterday in same time

Tags: azure, comparison, azure-application-insights, kql

Hi Kusto Query Language(KQL) lovers,

I am trying to write a query in **Kusto Query Language (KQL)**, that can compare **count** of APIs that failed **today** in a specific time (lets say 2:30 p.m. to 3 p.m.) with respect to **count** of APIs that failed **yesterday** in the same timeframe (2:30 p.m. to 3 p.m.).

For instance, if today, in last 30 min operation X was failed 10 times with failure code 400, I need to see count with which operation X failed today in last 30 minutes (Same time frame).

For this purpose, I used Scalar function **bin()** and wrote following query that extracts data from **request** table:

```
requests
|where timestamp > ago(1d)
| where client_Type != "Browser"
| where (cloud_RoleName == 'X')
| where name != 'HTTP GET'
| where success == false
| summarize count() by bin (timestamp, 1d), name, resultCode
|sort by timestamp
```

Here is the output I got when using **timestamp > ago(1d)**. This way, I was shown APIs that failed today and yesterday but there is no clear comparison between both dates.
[image: Output]

Is there any way I can display count of **APIs** that failed **yesterday** on separate Column adjacent to the **count_** Column that has count of corresponding **APIs** that failed **today**?
I know of **project** operator that adds extra column but I don't know how to incorporate and assign count of APIs that failed yesterday to project operator.

Kindly add to my knowledge of any relevant function or operator in KQL that can achieve this task.

The other way I tried was to define two variables, **startDateTime** and **endDateTime** to get the data of specific time as shown below.
Blank Output when I defined variables to define selected time frame:
[image: Blank output]

```
let startDateTime = todatetime("2023-02-07 06:35:00.0");
let endDateTime = todatetime("2023-02-07 06:35:00.0");
requests
|where timestamp > startDateTime and timestamp < endDateTime
| where client_Type != "Browser"
| where (cloud_RoleName == 'web-memberappservice-weu-prod')
| where name != 'HTTP GET'
| where success == false
| summarize count() by bin (timestamp, 1d), name, resultCode
|sort by timestamp
```

I searched about KQL query to compare count of failed APIs for today with respect to count of APIs that failed yesterday and checked some results from Stack overflow which are not helping me in achieving desired result.
I tried these links but queries on these links do not reflect what I want to achieve:

- [Best way to show today Vs yesterday Vs week in KQL azure monitror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74457708/best-way-to-show-today-vs-yesterday-vs-week-in-kql-azure-monitror)
- [kql query to compare the hour which has minimum number of TriggersStarted from last week to today past hour TriggersStarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74080734/kql-query-to-compare-the-hour-which-has-minimum-number-of-triggersstarted-from-l)

*What am I expecting?*
I want a query that can display count of **APIs** that failed **yesterday** on separate Column adjacent to the **count_** Column that has count of corresponding **APIs** that failed **today**.
I know of **project** operator that adds extra column but I don't know how to incorporate and assign count of APIs that failed yesterday to project operator.
Kindly identify any relevant function or operation that can help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

* The *where* clause was added for performance reasons.

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let requests = materialize(range i from 1 to 100000 step 1 | extend timestamp = ago(2d * rand()), name = tostring(dynamic(["PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "GET"])[toint(rand(4))]), resultCode = 400 + toint(rand(3)));
// Solution starts here.
let _period = 30m;
requests
| where     timestamp between (ago(_period)      .. _period)
        or  timestamp between (ago(_period + 1d) .. _period)   
| summarize todayCount      = countif(timestamp between (ago(_period)      .. _period)) 
           ,YesterdayCount  = countif(timestamp between (ago(_period + 1d) .. _period))
            by name, resultCode
 |sort by name asc, resultCode asc
```

| name | resultCode | todayCount | YesterdayCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GET | 400 | 91 | 100 |
| GET | 401 | 98 | 98 |
| GET | 402 | 109 | 89 |
| PATCH | 400 | 93 | 77 |
| PATCH | 401 | 84 | 85 |
| PATCH | 402 | 74 | 82 |
| POST | 400 | 78 | 85 |
| POST | 401 | 96 | 77 |
| POST | 402 | 85 | 102 |
| PUT | 400 | 98 | 81 |
| PUT | 401 | 97 | 85 |
| PUT | 402 | 77 | 83 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5VSTU8CMRC976944bRVwodwIxwMMXpSEvBgCDGFDkuT3Rbb2SCGH%208sLILxoM6lnc681/c6bbcx0cUmJxjNGhk5Cpqtdy08esZGB4ZfgdeE6PPyUElyYgR6KylyxBCFZgpW5/aD0qBdRrBYBV%20gC/bodqpAZNrIwR70zuQM2BYCl6uFQGc%20vTG4gqBNqlQTThckBfaRg3VZanZyYpfprDF%20njaaaIyfJsf1djp6qDb3d9PGXM3YW8fpgaev1FyoAsUy55E3FWFflFzjoqmnlBokbXmF2p0IFc8Rawp0dPq6EXfeCLrXKQbJyXiyx7ZqQhVnNwviLZFDWpmqoerQg1brxKUS1OHDb2DR2xWGC7DA5PJYFoUO8uZix%20jdyJeOj5xDLKvErtL/ylL4EibRfBEwhTP5X4l/SlaXvFjsDgO%20nE2CffTy1%20oSdFx%20G53knwQgtV%20rAgAA)

Comment: APIs in the 'name' column should not be limited to the ones that are shown above. I hide full APIs because of confidentiality agreement. What I want is that all APIs with success code == "false" should be displayed in 'name' column along with their respective failure count regardless of mentioning names of any specific API in the query. Also, I need count of failed APIs in a specific timeframe rather than failure count of full day.

Comment: **(1)** Where did you see in the code any reference to specific names? **(2)** What makes you think that the count is for a full day?

Comment: 1) I was referring to this part of your code regarding referencing to specific names. Please correct me if I am wrong.

name = tostring(dynamic(["PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "GET"])

2) Is this line not counting for previous 2 days?
| extend timestamp = ago(2d * rand()

Comment: Are you referring to the code laying between the 1st comment: **"Sample data generation. Not part of the solution."** to the 2nd comment: **"Solution starts here."**? As the comments hint, this part is for sample data generation (I make sure that my answers are tested and reproducible) and it is not part of the solution.